# mongoDB node API - Can't access result keys values?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm using mongoDB with **Mongoose** on Node.js with Express and tried to access a document in a collection like this one :

```
{ 
    _id:"ATypicalObjectID",
    name:"object",
    en:{AnotherObjectWithStuffInside}
}
```

With a function in my middleware as this one :

```
collection.findOne({name:"object"}).then(function(object){
  console.log(object, object.en, object[en], object.getValue("en"));
});
```

And the logged result is `{TheTextObjectmentionnedAbove}, undefined, undefined, {AnotherObjectWithStuffInside}`
But I can't understand why I've got these two `undefined` [(even on the mongoDB Node.js driver API)](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#findOne) and use this getValue() function only because I logged all of the result object keys ! (Is that a workaround or the good way to access a returned document value ?)

Comment: can you explain more and I think you need to recheck this code again...

Comment: @Shubham I edited my question, could you please be more precise about the part of my code I'ld need to recheck ? (I've simplified it)

Comment: where do you define text?

Comment: Haha, Yeah ! Sorry about that, it's the part I've simplified and forgot to switch variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,
Novice mistake : I needed to update my mongoose Schema to

```
{
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: String,
    en: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed
}
```

And now I can easily access to `object.en` !